# Neural Network Sensordata as Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, bigdata

I have a dataset consisting of sensor recordings about human movement. There are 22 classes of different movement like sitting or walking and 19 sensor values.

Each recording of a movement has about 1000 lines contained in a csv file.

[image: This is the test.csv file, that contains both the filename of a recording and the label that says, which movement was done during the recording.]

[image: This is an example of a movement recording, contains 19 sensor values and about 1000 lines]

My problem: I don't know how to present those recordings to a neural network (TensorFlow) so that it can be trained on the movement classes and even predict what was done in recording by getting those 19000 values.
I don't even know which Neural Network Model I should use and therefore need your help.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think you're going to have to provide a lot more info for us to help you. What exactly are you trying to predict? The 22 classes of movement? What does each CSV represent? Is that the movements from a single person? Is it safe to assume that one file can contain multiple movements? Are those movements already labeled for you in the files? What is your plan for data transforms? I think that you need to transform your data in some way to make it viable for a neural network. Also, how did you choose neural networks? Did you consider other models?

Comment: @I_Play_With_Data  
There are a bunch of test subjects. Each subject has provided about 60 files, that contain a recording of a specific movement. Each line is containing values of 19 sensors at this moment. A whole recording contains about 1000 values for each sensor.   Each file contains exactly one movement and those movements are already labeled.  But I don't know how to transform the data, as 19000 input values for each movement are a lot.

Comment: You may wish to Google for something like actigraphy & neutral network/ deep learning, you should find some examples of how other people have gone about this.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong: As far as I understood, you have files of 1000 entries with 19 numerical sensor values and a type of 22 movements in each line.
You would like to predict the type of movement based on the sensor values.

Are the entries being recorded in a fixed interval?
If so, you could use an [RNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent_quickdraw).

Either way, it seems to be a classification problem. You can find a tutorial for Tensorflow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification).

You can read data from csv files with [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

As for the encoding of your data: If the types of movement cannot be sorted and are not related to each other, you should use [one-hot encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f) to present the type of movement to the NN. You can keep numerical sensor data as is, just make sure to [normalize it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7757/data-normalization-and-standardization-in-neural-networks).

Comment: Almost. Not each line is representing a type of movement. But a file consisting of 1000 lines are representing a recording of the movement. So simply training the network on each line representing one movement is easy, but I don't know how to train the network on a whole recording. 19 * 1000 values are a lot so 19000 input neurons is bad, isn't it?

Thanks for your reply.